# When deploying ASP.NET web app on IIS in my local machine AngularJS does not work

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis

I've just developed an ASP.NET web application with VS2015 (.NET framework 4.6.1) which uses AngularJS via CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

If I launch it with Visual Studio it works, but if I deploy it to IIS in my local machine AngularJS doesn't work. Why?
So far I have followed this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b07128/deploy-Asp-Net-website-on-iis-in-our-local-machine/.

Comment: why you don't save `angular.min.js` file  locally in your project repository, and refer it from there..

Comment: I would anticipate it being an error related to file locations, depending on how you've deployed it. When you said "Doesn't work", what do you mean, are there any errors from IIS or in the console window in the browser?

Comment: no it simply doesn't solve angular expressions. I see {{5*3}} meanwhile I should see 15.

Comment: Ah right, that could still be an error in the console then to do with the library/another JS error, is there one? Do you know how to open the console and see if there are errors? Are you using Chrome?

Comment: Pankai now I try to save angular.min.js locally. I doesn't work anyways.

Comment: The console says that it has failed to load SignalR (in fact it doesn't work). That getPreventDefault() is deprecated and that "Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead".

Comment: If you are not using SignalR, then simply remove the references instead. On another note, the CDN reference will fail to work if you deploy to an HTTPS website, as it's an HTTP link.

Comment: But how can I know if my web site is HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: unless you've configureed it to be HTTPS it'll be HTTP, otherwise you can confirm this by checking the url. THis can be done by copying the url out of the url bar EG: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204314/when-deploying-asp-net-web-app-on-iis-in-my-local-machine-angularjs-does-not-wor` This is HTTP